# Object.values() is not defined even when using shim

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, shim

I'm struggling finding out why the shim of `Object.values` is not used. Error monitoring keeps raising issues like this one :

`Object.values is not a function. (In 'Object.values(L)', 'Object.values' is undefined)`

The problem is that I think I have provided a shim for browser not supporting `Object.values` :

```
// index.js

import 'es6-shim';
// ...


if (!Object.values) {
  require('object.values').shim();
}

global.App = {
  ...components,
  ...directives,
  ...mixins,
  ...filters,
  ...utils,
};

global.Vue = Vue;

global.ComponentsBootstrap = function ComponentsBootstrap(Vue) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    Raven
      .config('http://...')
      .addPlugin(RavenVue, Vue)
      .install()
    ;
  }

  const { provideComponents, provideDirectives, provideFilters } = global.App;

  Vue.use(provideComponents);
  Vue.use(provideDirectives);
  Vue.use(provideFilters);
};
```

And the code is used like :

```
 <script src="dist/components/app.js"></script>

 <script>
     ComponentsBootstrap(Vue);
     // include other components that use `Object.values()`
 </script>
```

Is it because the require('object.values').shim() isn't called inside the `function ComponentsBootstrap` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was bitten by the same problem using es6-shim as polyfill on some ES6 code running in IE11.  Sounds like es6-shim has few gaps solved by es7-shim e.g. https://github.com/es-shims/es7-shim